# .htaccess url rewrite inserts path to url

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I am running a magento website. I noticed that some **GET** parameter `foo=1` crashes one of the extensions. I would like to catch it and replace it with `foo=0` to prevent foo from being 1.
*(I need foo for other reasons and can't remove it completely)*

So I inserted this in my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=1(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?foo=1$ $1foo=0 [R=301,L]
```

I would expect this to rewrite:
`example.com/abc.html/?foo=1`
to:
`example.com/abc.html/?foo=0`

Instead, it rewrites it to:
`example.com/home/[folder]/public_html/abc.html/?foo=0`

(It adds file location path from home to the file **abc.html**. Htaccess file is located in **public_html**)

Can someone please tell me how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `/` before `$1foo=0 [R=301,L]` should solve that. So it would be

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=1(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?foo=1$ /$1foo=0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but that did not solve it. (I still get the home/.../public_html added to url)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+)\?(foo)=1[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2=0 [R=301,L]
```